# How to link to external site from NextJS

Tags: next.js

I feel like this is quite a basic question, but...how?

Googled various forms of this question and couldn't find a clear answer. I'm using NextJS and just want the user to click a button and be taken to a completely different site.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `router.push('https://www.google.com')` on the button's `onClick` callback? I'd recommend a read through [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a link styled like a button and put in the `href` that you want the user to visit. Something like this if you're using tailwind:

```
<Link href="https://www.google.com/">
  <a className="p-2 lg:px-4 mx-2 text-black text-center border border-solid border-black rounded ">Go to google</a>
</Link>
```

You can also add `target='_blank'` to the anchor if you want the URL to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet. We `passHref` in Link to pass the `href` to anchor tag so that the SEO will not hurt. Use   `target='_blank'` in the anchor tag to open the external link in the **new** tab.

```
<Link href="https://www.google.com/" passHref>
   <a target='_blank' >Go to google</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add  **rel="noopener"** inside the anchor tag bro.
If doesn't works then try adding **rel="noopener noreferrer"**.

```
    <Link href="https://www.google.com/" passHref>
       <a target='_blank' rel="noopener">Go to google</a>
    </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Link from "next/link";   //import this
 
<Link href="/">    //wrap a tag with Link
      <a>Home</a>
 </Link>

<Link href="https://nextjs.org">   //external page
      <a>Next.js</a>
 </Link>
```